# How to efficiently iterate and update a large string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I have a text file that is 6GB. I want to do something like:

```
str.gsub!('xxx', 'x')
```

The idea was to read 1MB chunks using seek. Is there a way to do the replacement above more efficiently? Perhaps iterating over the string using a C-like array access?

Comment: Does it have lines? Do you want to write the file back?

Comment: One option would be using `mmap` (unfortunately this requires a 3rd-party gem). If you decide to go with chunks then keep in mind you need to handle patterns spanning their boundaries as well, i.e. if the two first `x`s are at the end of the first chunk and the third `x` is at the beginning of the subsequent chunk.

Comment: Do you want `'xxxx'.sub('xxx', 'x') #=> => 'xx'`?

Comment: The most punishing part of `gsub` is the part where it has to rewrite the string. If you can instead scan for instances of `xxx` and skip over or rewrite those this will be significantly faster. There's no need to actually rewrite the string, just output to a file the good parts, plus the rewritten other parts.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I don't think we have that case. This is a simplified example.

Comment: @GregNavis - Good point. I'll need to handle this case.

Comment: @tadman - Not sure how it would work, but I want to update the file. Not necessary to rewrite the whole file, but just individual chars...? So `'xxx'` => `'x  '`.

Comment: Can you give an example here that's a lot more specific? Like a sample string and the desired output. Often `xxx` is just test data and the real-world situation is a lot more nuanced and complicated.

Comment: @tadman - The following unconventional quoting should be updated: `\foo"` -> `"foo"`, `""foo"` -> `"foo"`, `\"foo""` => `"foo"`.

Comment: `"...I want to update the file. Not necessary to rewrite the whole file, but just individual chars"`. That's impossible without rewriting. Text files are not fixed-size records so you can't arbitrarily shorten a line and expect the file to make sense. There is no "ignore these bytes then start reading text" marker in a text file, it's all significant information as far as the file read goes.

Comment: @theTinMan - https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-seek

Comment: You still can't write the file in-place with alterations that add or remove characters. You'll have to create a new file with new output. The process of inserting or deleting characters is the expensive part, and the cost grows with how many characters need to be shuffled left or right in the string buffer.

Comment: `seek` will locate a position in a file, but that won't fix the problem. A text file is a sequential file meaning it has to be read and written sequentially, you can't jump into a position and write an arbitrary number of characters and have the file automatically expand or contract. OSes, disks and files don't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a child process using `sed` which will be very fast:

```
`sed -i -E 's:xxx:x:g' file_name`
```

Comment: Ruby's line-by-line reading is fast but this would be faster since sed is written for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If the huge file has more than say, 20 lines, you could use :

```
File.open('new_file', 'w') do |out|
  File.foreach('huge_file.txt') do |line|
    out.puts line.gsub('xxx', 'x')
  end
end
```

This will have a very low memory footprint and should be reasonably fast.

Comment: What if the 6GB file has two lines? :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: True. Updated.

Comment: @EricDuminil The file has millions of lines.

Comment: If it has millions of lines, then reading line-by-line and using `gsub` on each line is as fast as it'll get in pure Ruby. You can't read using blocks because you could get `xx` at the end of a block and miss the fact it's really `xxx` because the next block starts with `x`. Using `sed` would be even faster, as long as the spawning speed of the subshell doesn't eat up the benefit.